# How to convert a ternary operator into a conditional operator?

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, operators, conditional-operator

Basically I need to transform a ternary operator into a conditional operator using "if...else" cycle.

```
function getBestStudent (students) {

const bestAverageMark = students.reduce((a, b) => getAverageMark(a) > getAverageMark(b) ? a : b)

return bestAverageMark
}
```

"getAverageMark" here is another function.

How can I transform this into a conditional operator "if... else"? Thank you!

Comment: do you mean rewriting to `if (getAverageMark(a) > getAverageMark(b)) { return a; } else { return b; }`? you might wanna check out the [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25276124/js-ternary-operator-vs-if-else) on ternary operators vs if-else statements

Comment: Yes, but i also need to understand when i must insert the .reduce method.

Comment: is your current code working correctly and you just want to replace the ternary operator w/ an if-else statement? if not, then you might rephrase your question because i don't understand it any longer; i don't know what you mean by "insert the .reduce method"

Comment: My actual code is working well, but in the code i have this part: `students.reduce((a, b)` and i don't understand where i must insert `students.reduce((a, b)` in the if-else statement. I tried a lot, but i still can't understand how to convert the ternary operator in the conditional if-else statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might wanna check out the [mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) on arrow function expressions

```js
function getBestStudent (students) {
  const bestAverageMark = students.reduce((a, b) => {
     if (getAverageMark(a) > getAverageMark(b)) {
       return a;
     } else {
       return b;
    }
  });

  return bestAverageMark;
}
```

this could be simplified to

```js
function getBestAverageMark (a,b) {
  if (getAverageMark(a) > getAverageMark(b)) {
    return a;
  } else {
    return b;
  }
}

function getBestStudent (students) {
  return students.reduce(getBestAverageMark);
}
```

Comment: Yes, of course. Thank you